# What's the difference between "angry with" and "angry towards"

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

May I know the difference between "angry with" and "angry towards" in these sentences:
1-He felt very angry towards her.
2-He felt very angry with her.

Comment: _Angry with_ is the usual expression, though you could talk about his  _anger towards her_

Comment: Idiomatically, it's usually [*He **is** angry **with**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+angry+with%2Cis+angry+towards%2Cfeels+angry+with%2Cfeels+angry+towards&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) [someone who annoyed him]*. The versions with ***feels** and/or **towards*** aren't particularly common, so *some* native speakers might assume that if they heard them from a speaker *known or believed to be competent in the use of English*, some subtly different meaning was intended. But there's no well-established alternative interpretation, so just forget about them

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Happy new year.